# t_delta too long error on Freenas 0.7.1

Tags: freebsd, zfs, truenas

I am using FreeNas 0.7.1 (FreeBSD 7.2-release-p6) Recently I have been getting a series of these error messages to the console.  I am using ZFS pools mirrored on the FreeNAS system, and they report as healthy and in good status.

I think this error message is related to the FreeBSD underneath. The ZFSpools are iscsi targets for a VMWare installation over Gigabit network.  Is the delta_t they are referring to talking about a potential time out for packets over iSCSI?  Has anyone experienced this error message?  I have attached an image below.

[image: t_delta_too_long]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an error with the time clock on your computer, has nothing to do with ZFS, iSCSI, etc.

Try updating your MB's BIOS. Or post the make/model and we might be of more help. In any case it's nothing to worry about if the clock is still correct.

Comment: Really, it is a clock issue?  The reason I guessed about ZFS or iSCSI was that I had a pci-e card with two drives fail and cause a ZFS I/O panic a few days before this.  The model motherboard is ASUS P5BV-C

Comment: There aren't any other reports of people having problems with that board, but the error is definitely clock related (specifically making adjustments to the clock). I suppose it's remotely possible the failed card did something to the MB.

Comment: I adjusted the time on the system using the `date` command.  But t_delta is still printing too long and also too short errors.  This is a production server so I have to wait for the weekend to take it down to check the time and date in the BIOS.